# jQuery: How do I insert link text into input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an Ajax Live Search. My goal: When you click on one of the suggested results, the result shall be inserted into the search field. For example, when you enter "ros" into the input field and you want to look for roses and roses is a result suggested to you, then I want roses to show up in the search field on click.

```
<!-- Lets assume that up to this point the user has typed "ros" 
into the following field -->
<input id="search" type="text">

<!-- ... then roses is a suggested result, with "ros" being highlighted -->
<ul id="results">
  <li class="result">
    <a> 
      <b class="highlight">ros</b>"es"</p>
    </a>
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery code that I have come up with so far, but it won't work:

```
$('#results a').click(function() {
    var selection = $(this).html();
    $('#search').val(selection);
});
```

Anyone has detected the error?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post this on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `$(this).text().trim()` instead of `$(this).html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be case of event delegation:

```
$('#results').on('click', 'a', function() {
```

---

what i see you have some dynamically generated links in the list as if user searches for something. if this is the case then you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent which is in your case is `#results` because an event is not bound to dynamically generated elements *as they were not available when you bound the event*.

Also there is a notice as you have a closing tag of `</p>` which doesn't have a opening tag. also if you want to place the text of the clicked element then you don't have to use `.html()`, you can use `.text()` method instead.

Comment: many thanks, it has worked. why event delegation? what's behind it?

Comment: Probably because he inferred that you are creating your links dynamically and thus they are not the part of DOM at the moment of attaching the handler by $('#results a').click(...). Using delegation as he did it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yout HTML is invalid. You have a closing `</p>` without an opening one inside your `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think you should simply use `$(this).html()` as it will include the html-tags, and you probably don't want that inserted.

But I think the reason you can't get it to work (I'm assuming absolutely nothing happens) is because you set the listener before the results are loaded, and hence they aren't bound to the links. Use `$('#results').on('click', 'a', function(){})` to bind events "up front".

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#results a').click(function() {
    var selection = $(this).text();
    $('#search').val((selection.replace("\"", "")).replace("\"", ""));
});
```

Comment: Providing a code-only answer isn't usually particularly helpful.  You should add some context, explain what you're doing, and/or why you're doing it.

Comment: thank you for your comments... i am learning english... i speak spanish.